# How can I create this shape in blender?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create this abstract shape in Blender but I am not succeeding. I am new to Blender and shapes like this are hard for me to create. I need some guidance from experts/artists.

[image]

Comment: mmh this one is very hard indeed   ^^  actually you don't show any shape, so please edit your message

Comment: @moonboots Use your imagination! :^) To the poster: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of rings doesn't have to be the exact same (You can tweak as needed to get what you want), here's what you can do:

1. Add an Empty.
2. Add a Nurbs Curve. Select two vertices and subdivide until there are 8 vertices.
3. Position them in the shape of a hexagon, putting the two remaining vertices (which should be the ends) between their preceding vertices, like so:
   [image]
4. Object > Convert > Mesh, then add a Skin Modifier, Subdivision Modifier, then Array Modifier. In Edit Mode, if you select all vertices and press Ctrl + A, you can adjust the thickness of the Skin Modifier. I set it to 0.4, and no, I have no idea why that's not a setting in the Modifier itself... Subdivisions should be at least but probably no more than two for the sake of your computer's happiness, and as for the Array, make the Count *72*, set the first value of Relative Offset to 0, check Object Offset, then make the Target Object the Empty.
5. In Edit Mode, select everything and rotate it upright, then move it off to the side so the ending vertices line up with the origin. If you want to be exact, use Object Snapping (with Absolute Grid Snap checked) and then select all of the vertices then one of the ending vertices WITH "ACTIVE ELEMENT" SELECTED as your Transform Pivot Point option right next to the Magnetic "Snap" indicator, move with G, tap X or Y to move it by whichever axis, more than once if needed until you're moving globally, and move until lined up with the origin.
   [image]
6. Rotate the Empty a mere 5 degrees on the Z axis and voila, you should have your shape. You can Convert to Mesh again to apply the Modifiers and then Shade Smooth, which if you want to make changes, you might want to do on a duplicate so you don't have to do this all over again.
   [image]

To determine the depth of the converging centers and the rest of the shape's curvature, you'll need to do some trial and error with the Nurbs Curve.

To determine the amount of rings, adjust the Count value of the Array and rotation of the Empty as needed.

Comment: It worked man! Thank you very much @Valkyrie9001.  https://i.postimg.cc/mrz66bQB/Screenshot-2022-11-10-at-6-25-04-PM.png

Comment: @Abinashkumar Awesome stuff. If you're able to mark my answer as a solution, I would appreciate it. Helps me out. ♥